# Python: Ignoring signals in background process

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

I am creating a Python program that calls an external command periodically. The external command takes a few
seconds to complete. I want to reduce the possibility of the external command terminating
badly by adding a signal handler for SIGINT. Basically,  I want SIGINT to attempt to wait until the command
executes before terminating the Python program. The problem is that the external perogram seems to be
getting the SIGINT as well, causing it to end abruptly. I am invoking the command using an external thread, since
the Python documentation for signal mentions that only the main thread receives the signal, according to http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html.
Can someone help with this.
Here is a stub of my code. Imagine that the external program is /bin/sleep:

```
import sys
import time
import threading
import signal
def sleep():
  import subprocess
  global sleeping
  cmd = ['/bin/sleep', '10000']
  sleeping  = True
  p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  p.wait()
  sleeping = False

def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
  if sleeping:
     print 'busy, will terminate shortly'
     while(sleeping): time.sleep(0.5)
     sys.exit(0)
  else:
     print 'clean exit'
     sys.exit(0)

sleeping = False
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
while(1):
  t1 = threading.Thread(target=sleep)
  t1.start()
  time.sleep(500)
```

The expected behavior is that pressing Ctrl+C N seconds after the program starts will result in 
it waiting (10000 - N) seconds and then exiting. What is happening is the program immediately terminates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the way signal handlers are modified when executing a new process. From POSIX:

```
A child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's signal dis‐
positions.  During an execve(2), the dispositions  of  handled  signals
are  reset to the default; the dispositions of ignored signals are left
unchanged.
```

So what you need to do is:

1. Ignore the SIGINT signal
2. Start the external program
3. Set the SIGINT handler as desired

That way, the external program will ignore SIGINT.

Of course, this leaves a (very) small time window when your script won't respond to SIGINT. But that's something you'll have to live with.

For example:

```
sleeping = False
while(1):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=sleep)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    t1.start()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
    time.sleep(500)
```

Comment: Thanks isedev! Sorry for my delayed response, other tasks took precedence. Your solution appears like it should work, but for some reason the spawned process is still receiving the signal. My updated main loop is the same as what you posted. Could there be some Python-specific intricacy I'm overlooking?

Comment: How could I ignore the `SIGINT signal`

Comment: `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)`